# Find class method by value

Tags: c#, class, methods

How to make a search method for a class object that finds a property that contains the searched value?

I now the class property has string value - "Anna", but I need to know what property holds it.

Tell if need more information.

```
class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        First first = new First()
        {
            Name = "Anna",
            Nick = "Alise"
        };

        string find = "Anna";

        string some = first.Equals_SomeMethodWith(find);// How to do this?
      Console.WriteLine(some);
    }
        
}

class First
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Nick { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Do you mean something like `if(first.First == find) { Console.WriteLine("It's in the first name"); }`?

Comment: Are you hoping `first.Equals_SomeMethodWith(find);` will output `"Name"`?

Comment: we need way more clarification here. To "hold" a value one would use a property or a field. Methods actually don't hold values, they should perform actions. Please try to describe a little more what you mean by  "I now the class object have string value - "Anna", but I need to know what method hold it." is the name of the method supposed to contain "Anna" ?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit and rephrase your question according to the new information that you have provided in your comments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean properties, not methods, then something like:

```cs
var props = first.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        try
        {
            if (prop.GetValue(first) is string val && val == find)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}={val}");
            }
        }
        catch { } // best efforts
    }
}
```

---

Or for an array (comments):

```cs
First[] objects = new[] {
    new First()
    {
        Name = "Fred",
        Nick = "Freddy"
    },
    new First()
    {
        Name = "Anna",
        Nick = "Alise"
    },
    new First()
    {
        Name = "Robert",
        Nick = "Bob"
    },
};

string find = "Anna";
var index = Array.FindIndex(objects, x => AnyPropEquals(x, find));
Console.WriteLine(index);


static bool AnyPropEquals<T>(object obj, T value)
{
    var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(T))
        {
            try
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(obj) is T val && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(val, value))
                    return true;
            }
            catch { } // best efforts
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Array have method Array.IndexOf(arr, searchElement). In my case Class.someThink(First, "Anna"), 
Class have some think like this?

Comment: @PavelsFilipovs ah so you need a method that looks at every property and field of a class and tries to find a given value like a string in your example ?

Comment: Yes, correct. The method are already in default, method I wrote?

Comment: @PavelsFilipovs you didn't mention arrays in the question - only a single object; see edit

Comment: @PavelsFilipovs if you *know which property*: then it is much much simpler (and much more efficient): `var index = Array.FindIndex(objects, x => x.Name == find);`

Comment: @MarcGravell I think OP used the array as an example. Seems they want to search within a class like within an array. I have the feeling that your first answer actually hit bullseye.

Comment: @PavelsFilipovs Is the method suppose to return anything? yield the propertyname may be ?

Comment: in array search I know 100k+ can get examples, but my question is - get method name by value in Class object. In what class have the method who can help do it or know how to do it simple?

Comment: @PavelsFilipovs "get method name by value" why method? what do you understand under the termn "method" ? `public string Name { get; set; }` this contains the value `"Anna"` that you are searching.... but this is **not** a method!

Comment: @PavelsFilipovs honestly, what you really need here is a good example that shows what you're trying to do, even if it contains a "something here" gap - but which shows the expected setup, and the expected result. Right now, it seems like every time you clarify something, you move the goalposts completely (and whatever game is being metaphorically played: I'm not even sure that it uses goalposts)